# Using multiple generics in the method signature in Java

Tags: java

I have a interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {

   Map<Long, T> getMap();

}
```

and two classes that implement it. The first one is:

```
public class MyInterfaceFileImpl implements MyInterface<File> {

  private Map<Long, File> map;

  public MyInterfaceFileImpl(Map<Long, File> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<Long, File> getMap() {
    return map;
  }

}
```

The second one is:

```
public class MyInterfaceStringImpl implements MyInterface<String> {

  private Map<Long, String> map;

  public MyInterfaceStringImpl(Map<Long, String> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<Long, String> getMap() {
    return map;
  }

}
```

I would like to pass the interface as a parameter to a method called `doSomething()`.

```
public <T extends MyInterface<S>> void doSomething(T myInterface) {

  Map<Long, S> ret = doSomething.getMap();

}
```

In this case, S would be `String` if I pass `MyInterfaceStringImpl` implementation and `File` if I pass `MyInterfaceFileImpl` implementation

I have two questions:

1. How to define the type `S` in `doSomething()` method.
2. Looking at what I'm trying to achieve in `doSomething()` method, am I using generics correctly or I should go for another solution?

Comment: How about `MyInterface<?> myInterface` instead of `T myInterface`? Do you need the `S` for anything? You don't know anything about the type `S`, after all.

Comment: I need the S to define the Map ret.

Comment: It sounds like you need `<T> void doSomething(MyInterface<? extends T>)` (if you're going to use `ret` somewhere below) or, as suggested by Sweeper, `MyInterface<?>` (if you don't care its type parameter at all).

Comment: Is `S` a generic?

Comment: If I use this:
`public <T> void doSomething(MyInterface<? extends T) myInterface`

Will I be able to use `File` and `String` methods?

Comment: Not without type casting which I find bad. `<T>` is essentially `java.lang.Object` in this case so there is nothing very common. I guess, if I see what you mean, you'd like to have a common type both `String` and `File` can be wrapped into, say interface `Wrapper` with some common methods. Probably then your `MyInterface` might even discard type parameterization in favor of the wrapper interface `Wrapper` like this `interface MyInterface { Map<Long, Wrapper> getMap(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add the S generic argument before T like so:

```java
    public <S, T extends MyInterface<S>> void doSomething(T myInterface)
    {

        Map<Long, S> ret = myInterface.getMap();

    }
```

Commenting on point 2: I don't see any problem with the usage.